# To cut sth in half using teeth

Tags: word-request, verbs, vocabulary, translation

In the Czech language we can say *"překousnout"* to express literally *"to cut sth in half using teeth"* just with one word. This is used e.g. in the context of sewing when scissors are not at hand and we need to bite the cotton thread to short and cut it. We can do the same with a piece of adhesive tape.

**Is there an elegant translation of this verb in English** and would you give me an example of the usage in a sentence?

The only translation I have found is *"to bite sth in two"* on a doubtful online dictionary on the czech domain.

Comment: Maybe "bite off with your teeth"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a single word in English to describe what you're looking for. ***Rip something with your teeth*** is about as elegant as it gets. For example:

> John: I don't have scissors to cut this tape.
>
> Mary: Then rip it with your teeth.

You could also use ***tear it with your teeth***, ***tear it in two***, ***tear it in half***, or ***tear off a piece***, but "tear" or "rip" doesn't necessarily imply with teeth. You can tear or rip with fingers or hands as well.